# Prevent user to access each user pages

Tags: php, session

I have 3 kinds of users [admin, student, instructor], I want to prevent each user to access each page. e.g when the session started for the student, the student cannot access the admin page or instructor and same for other users.
this is  the code that I applied

```
@session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['user']){

    header("Location: HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found", 404);

    exit();

}
```

but this code will prevent the user to don't access the page if the session has not been started yet.

Also I applied this to my admin page and it works because the user for admin is fixed user.

```
@session_start();

if((!$_SESSION['user']) or ($_SESSION['user']!='admin'))
{

    header("Location: HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found", 404);
    exit();

}
```

I saw some answer, but did not help to solve my issue. Please help me.

Comment: You're looking for `isset()` and `elseif()` don't you?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be best, if you created **a separate PHP file that undertakes the task to send the user to the correct destination for their user level**, which will in turn render the redirection to a `404 page` pointless.

To do that, I would write your PHP code as shown:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
        switch ($_SESSION["user"]) {
            case "user":
                // redirect to the "user" page
            case "instructor":
                // redirect to the "instructor" page
            case "admin":
                // redirect to the "admin" page
        }
    }
?>
```

Doing it this way, you will ensure that **each user will always be landed to the correct page for their user level** and you will not need to redirect your users to ugly 404 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to write a simple function, and if they are not yet signed in - display them the login form, if they are signed in but they don't have the sufficient privileges, tell them and forward them back to the previous page they visited or the home page.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (!isLoggedIn())
      logonForm();
   else if ($_SESSION["user"] != "admin")
      {
         echo "You don't have the sufficient privileges to open this page.";
         header( "refresh:5; url=index.php" );
      }
    else
      display();
?>
```

You can also wrap the above into a function so you can include it to every page.